# glPolygonMode in OpenGLES

Tags: opengl-es

Is there an equivalent to glPolygonMode in OpenGL ES? How do you render wireframe in OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Use `GL_LINES`.

Comment: What if you are tessellating?

Comment: @Makogan HW or sofware tessellating? OpenGL ES do not expose the tesselator AFAIK. If you need to display the wireframe, the best way is to prepare indices to draw the wireframe.

Comment: OpenGL ES 3.2 does expose tessellation

Comment: Oh sorry. Anyway this should work too because tesselation is the same for both lines or triangles. See Pixar's OSD library/ Maya, they use both tesselator and wireframe (rendered as lines) https://www.fxguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/eilnorbear.jpg

Comment: @Makogan Note that you can also render the wireframe as part of the fragment shader, but I don't like this approach because when the triangle of an edge is backface you only see half of the edge.